# How can I make the button text a specific color Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Right now I can make it one of the given xcode color like black, blue, red, etc. However, I want to make it a specific color, aqua to be exact. Can anyone help me?

```
button1Label.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @code How would I use that to change it to a specific color

Comment: @cod because I will need different colors for different situations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your Color by

> UIColor(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)

So it will be:

```
let yourColor = UIColor(red: 165.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 178.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) 

button1Label.setTitleColor(yourColor, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RGB function of UIColor like so:

```
button1Label.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom UIColor Object. In Swift, you instantiate a custom UIColor object with an initializer.

There are several available to us, some more useful than others:

> init(white: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
>
> init(hue: CGFloat, saturation: CGFloat, brightness: CGFloat, alpha:
>   CGFloat)
>
> init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
>
> init(CGColor cgColor: CGColor!) init(patternImage image: UIImage)
>
> init(CIColor ciColor: CIColor)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use RGB colors.
This is my favorite way of doing it with Swift

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(rgb r: Int, _ g: Int, _ b: Int, _ a: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/255, green: CGFloat(b)/255, blue: CGFloat(b)/255, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

and call it with

```
let color = UIColor(rgb: 150, 135, 85)
let color2 = UIColor(rgb: 100, 120, 200, 0.5)
```